# reading just one line from file in c code

Tags: c, file, printing

My program reads the specific line from the file properly, however it reads the whole file form the line I specify onward. I am trying to print just one line at a time. How can I make it just read the one line?

The code:

```
int main() 
{
  int lineNumber = 5;
  static const char filename[] = "Text.txt";
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
  int count = 0;

  if ( file != NULL )
  {
    char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
    {
        if (count == lineNumber)
        {
            printf("%s", line);
            //in case of a return first close the file with "fclose(file);"
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out the link http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line

Answer (score 1):

After you've found the desired line, just use a `break` to exit the loop:

```
if (count == lineNumber)
{
  printf("%s", line);
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count == lineNumber)
        {
            printf("%s", line);
            //in case of a return first close the file with "fclose(file);"
            count++;
        }
```

increment `count` when you get the line you specify,otherwise `count` will not proceed to indicate next line. That is why your code printed all lines once you got the line you specified. Because the line number `count` wont increase once it becomes equal to linenumber. so add `count++`.
You can even `break` the loop since you don't require rest of the lines to be read after you get the specified line.